# Computer doesn't start

Tags: boot, laptop, motherboard, fan

A while back, my computer started to act weird : when I pressed the "on" button, all the leds turned on, but the screen was black, and after a while, it starts up. This delay kept getting longer and longer until the day the computer screen stayed black and never booted (while the leds were on).

I thought it was a problem related to RAM, so here's what I noticed :

- When the RAM is plugged, the leds and fan start, then stop, then the led are on (without the fan).
- When the RAM is unplugged, the leds and fan are on all along.

In both cases, the screen is pitch black.

This is not a SMART issue, as I tried with another HDD, neither is it Wifi, CD Drive, keybord or any peripheral.

Alse, I'd like to precise that my computer has been running without fan for several months.

Comment: "my computer has been running without fan for several months" - Dead CPU?

Comment: Ran the PC without the fan, the delay kept getting longer, then it finally quit. Since you didn't ask a question, are you telling us your PC is fried (because that is what it sounds like)?

Comment: Well, by fried, you mean dead motherboard or dead CPU ?

Comment: My expert guess is that the power supply is bad.